Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'mode') vercel deployment laravel

I want to deploy using vercel through the CLI and when I run vercel build everything is safe until npm run build then not long ago it appears the error setting 'mode' I don't know where the error is or what I mean 'mode' is the error where the error is and i use laravel

Somehow found a bug inside .vercel\builders\node_modules\vercel-php\dist\utils.js of Laravel project directory
changed from this (Line 53):
runtimeFiles['php/php'].mode = 33261; // 0755;
runtimeFiles['php/composer'].mode = 33261; // 0755;

to this:
if (runtimeFiles['php/php']) {
    runtimeFiles['php/php'].mode = 0o755;
}
if (runtimeFiles['php/composer']) {
    runtimeFiles['php/composer'].mode = 0o755;
}

solved the problem for me
